# DeepEqual: Why does an unmarshalled map return DeepEqual() results differently than a seemingly identical literal

Tags: json, go

I don't understand how to compare unmarshalled JSON.  Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    a := map[string]interface{} {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
    b := map[string]interface{} {"bar": 2, "foo": 1}
    fmt.Printf("Literal B is %v, DeepEqual is %v\n", b, reflect.DeepEqual(a, b))

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"bar": 2, "foo": 1}`), &b)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Could not unmarshal")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Umarshalled B is %v, DeepEqual is %v\n", b, reflect.DeepEqual(a, b))
}
```

prints

*Literal B is map[bar:2 foo:1], DeepEqual is **true***

*Umarshalled B is map[bar:2 foo:1], DeepEqual is **false***

What is different about the B initialized from a literal and B after JSON is unmarshalled upon it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answers your question:

```
fmt.Printf("%T\n", b["foo"]) // Prints "float64" after unmarshaling.
```

JSON numbers are 64-bit floating point numbers, while your original map values were integers. From the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

Comment: Perfect!  I changed to

    a := map[string]interface{} {"foo": 1.0, "bar": 2.0};
    b := map[string]interface{} {"bar": 2.0, "foo": 1.0}

and it worked as expected.

Comment: @esnible If this answers your question, you should accept it by [clicking on the check mark](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).